# how to isolated string that contain TAB?

Tags: c#

i have this string:

```
i[TAB]like[TAB]Stackoverflow
```

and i need to get this:

```
i

like

Stackoverflow
```

how to do it in C# ?

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to be more specific: Do you want the result as a single string (with newlines instead of tabs), or as an array of strings (split at each tab)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If by "isolated" you mean explode that into an array,

```
return thatString.Split("\t");
```

Answer (score 10):

```
mystring = mystring.Replace("\t","\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: Why did this answer get voted down?  It's absolutely correct.

Comment: @Ari: depends on what the OP _actually_ wants. As usual that's not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
str.Split("\t");
```

will return an array of strings.